# Optimization of Regex

Tags: java, regex, optimization

I am using jprofiler to help me reduce the CPU usage. Here are my two scenarios:

Scenario 1:

```
//Global Variables
    static Pattern escapeSequences = Pattern.compile("(\\r|\\n|\\t)");
    static Pattern printableCharacters = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Print}]");

     String message = String.format(format, args);


          return printableCharacters.matcher(escapeSequences.matcher(message).replaceAll("")).replaceAll("?");
```

Scenario 2:

```
            for (int i=0; i<args.length; ++i) {
                if (args[i] instanceof String) {
                    args[i].replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)","").replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "?");
                }
            }

return formater = String.format(format, args);
```

Scenario 1 runs in approximately 9% while scenario 2 runs in approximately 7%. What i do not understand here is that if the regex is pre-compiled once as opposed to every time, why is the cpu higher? What can I do to reduce the CPU below 7%.

Comment: please realize regexp in most languages are not optimized for speed: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html

Comment: First write your patterns in the right way: first pattern `"[\\r\\t\\n]+"` *(an alternation can have an high cost, the quantifier allows to remove several consecutive characters instead of one by one)*, second pattern: `"\\P{Print}"` *(more concise to negate a `\\p{...}` character class, will not change performances)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe  that the following line: `String.format(format, args);` is the reason.

In the first example, You execute it prior to replacing characters, in second, You do it post. Depending on `format` variable, the processed string might get a lot bigger in first example, affecting the execution time.

Moreover, in second example the loop is not doing anything useful - `replaceAll` creates new `String` reference, and You are not assigning it anywhere. The compiler might just optimize this section and throw this loop away. Bottom line is that the result is different from the one returned by first example.

Comment: The second part of this answer is spot on. The compiler will most definitely get rid of a loop that is a nop.